# Unable to read JSESSIONID or Cookie details in javascript

Tags: javascript, tomcat, cookies, dojo, jsessionid

I have a situation , where multiple apps are deployed on the same tomcat server. These application has `DOJO` framework as UI.

We are trying to move From `DOJO` to `Angular` but in phases. So Few pages where we have angular implemented UI should be popped from `DOJO` UI when cicked.

Whenever user logs into the application, authentication happens, session is created. I believe Tomcat container maintains this `JSESSIONID` and validates future request.

ALL future requests, I can see that request header has Cookie with 3 `JSESSIONID`.

I was looking to read this `JSESSIONID` and pass it onto `Angular` UI while launching it. 
But am unable to read the cookie in browser console of DOJO app.

I tried document.cookie and it returned ""(empty string). I cross checked `web.xml` of the application to see if they have made HTTPOnly in context configuration to secure cookie and couldn't find anything of that sort.

How to read this `JSESSIONID` from `DOJO` app and pass it to `Angular` APP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried 'dojo/cookie'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `"dojo/cookie"`

you can access  directly cookie by name as `console.log(cookie("JSESSIONID"));`

See example of setting and getting cookies in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lh2upecg/)

ps (can't make snippet due to iframe security in stackoverflow )

Comment: have you tried this , also does your app run under Iframe ?